# how to make the background of the heading the same length as the heading?

Tags: html, css

Ive been trying to make the background of the heading the same width as the heading and also want the background image to resize automatically to fit the heading. Please help and see the fiddle :[here](http://jsfiddle.net/Zb6KV/)

Markup:

```
<div class="custom-section-head">

<h3>news</h3>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.custom-section-head {
background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use floats:

See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Zb6KV/4/

```
.custom-section-head {
    background: red;
    float:left;
}

h3 {
    float:left;
  }
```

Then the h3 and the container will be the size of the heading. However, why not just add the background the head `<h3>` element?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting class for `div`, you can add a `span` for that..

```
<h3><span class="custom-section-head">news</span></h3>
```

Here is the updated **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zb6KV/3/)**

Comment: great thanks..but how would i place an image behind it so that it fits perfectly..background-position does not seem to work?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that a `div` element is a block level element.  That means it will take the full width of the space available.  Assigning the background to this element means it will also fill the full width of the space available.

What else will go inside that div?  The best answer largely depends on that.

There's a few techniques to use.  It depends on what you want from the layout.

I personally prefer using the `display:inline-block;` technique:

```
.custom-section-head {
    background: red;
    display:inline-block;
    /* IE7 Hack to make inline-block work */
    zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
}
```

But, that will allow additional elements to display inline (to the right of) with the head div, which may not be desirable in this case.

Alternatively, float (as @robooneus points out) will accomplish what you want:

```
.custom-section-head {
    float: left;
    background: red;
}
```

Finally, you could use a full "inline" layout (probably not the correct option, but for completeness I've included it):

```
.custom-section-head {
    display:inline;
    background: red;
}

.custom-section-head h3 {
    display:inline;
}
```

But if you did that, it would be better to use "native" inline elements, such as `span` instead of `div`.

Ideally, however, you would identify **all** of the elements that will be contained in your head element, so that we could help define the best possible layout / styling for your situation.

Comment: thanks.. it will just be

   <h3><span class="custom-section-head">news</span></h3>, where i want news to be on top of an image, like a ribbon or so?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively:

HTML:

```
<h3><span>news</span></h3>
```

CSS:

```
h3 span {
    background-color:red
}
```

You can use `background-size: contain;` to make the background image fit, if you are prepared to degrade for IE8